# Storing Array Values to Objects Only Stores first value and keeps Repeating the Value Over And Over

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object, puppeteer

Im new to JavaScript so I dont have good Programming Skills rightnow, so I have been working on a Web Scraper That returns an Array of Name,Posts,Bio etc like this:

```
let infoOfPost = await newTab(browser, page);
```

So infoOfPost is an Array whose value is changinging since it is being called in a loop and i can see it in console that every time it has new values for bio,posts,followers etc.
But when I push this value to an Object, the Object only store the initial value when loop ran for the first time and in every next iteration it just keeps displaying same value and does not overwrites the previous value Im storing array in objec as:

```
    accountInfoObject.displayName =infoOfPost[0];
    accountInfoObject.posts = infoOfPost[1];
    accountInfoObject.followers=infoOfPost[2];
    accountInfoObject.following =infoOfPost[3];
    accountInfoObject.fullName = infoOfPost[4];
    accountInfoObject.about =infoOfPost[5];
    accountsInformation.push(accountInfoObject);
    await objectsCsv(accountsInformation);
```

What Im seeing right now is something like this:

```
[
 {
   accountUrl: 'https://www.example.com/xyz.hij/',
   displayName: 'saharpalmer',
   posts: '368',
   followers: '2,640',
   following: '510',
   fullName: 'Sahar Intuitive Life Mentor',
   about: '30-year Experience: I help you shift your mindsetGet back on track quickly Fulfil your purpose & live your best life'
  }
]
```

What I want to see is that all other entries of mine come after it with a comma and make it an Array of Objects instead of Array of Single Object.
Currently I only see this Once and the this Array of single Object keeps repeating. Also I am pushing this Object to an Array and writing it to Csv File the file which also contains this Object repeating again and again looks like this:

```
about   accountUrl  displayName posts   followers   following   fullName
30-year Experience: I help you shift your mindset??Get back on track quickly??Fulfil your purpose & live your best life??'  https://www.example.com/being.darsh/    saharpalmer 368 2640    510 Sahar
30-year Experience: I help you shift your mindset??Get back on track quickly??Fulfil your purpose & live your best life??'  https://www.example.com/being.darsh/    saharpalmer 368 2640    510 Sahar
```

The Object and Array declaration are as:

```
let accountsInformation = [];
let accountInfoObject = new Object();
```

Full Code is:
The file where we are getting Array back is:

```
let accountsInformation = [];
let accountInfoObject = new Object();
async function scrapingPosts(browser, page) {
  readCsvFile(urlsToVisit);
  for (let x = 0; x < urlsToVisit.length; x++) {
    secondaryUrl = urlsToVisit[x];
    await page.waitFor(10000);
    await page
      .goto(`${secondaryUrl}`, {
        waitUntil: "domcontentloaded",
      })
      .catch((e) => {});
    await page.waitForSelector("article >div.EZdmt:nth-child(2)",
      5000);
    for (let i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
      await page.waitFor(5000);
      //  this loops goes through all 3 posts of each container;
      for (let j = 1; j <= 3; j++) {
        // opening the modal means clicking on post i and j will 
        increment and we will keep moving to next post 1 by 1
        await page.click(
          `div.EZdmt > div > div > div:nth-child(${i}) > div:nth-child(${j})`);
        let url = await urlOfIds(page, urlsAddress);
        await page.waitFor(5000);
        let infoOfPost = await newTab(browser, page);
        accountInfoObject.accountUrl = url;
        accountInfoObject.displayName = infoOfPost[0];
        accountInfoObject.posts = infoOfPost[1];
        accountInfoObject.followers = infoOfPost[2];
        accountInfoObject.following = infoOfPost[3];
        accountInfoObject.fullName = infoOfPost[4];
        accountInfoObject.about = infoOfPost[5];
        await page.waitFor(10000);
        accountsInformation.push(accountInfoObject);
        console.log(accountsInformation);
        await objectsCsv(accountsInformation);
        // Modal Closes here process repeats till the loop condition is unsatisfied
        await page.click(
          "body > div._2dDPU.QPGbb.CkGkG > div.qF0y9._4EzTm.BI4qX.qJPeX.fm1AK.TxciK.yiMZG >button.wpO6b");
        await page.waitFor(20000);
      }
    }
  }
  await browser.close();
}
```

The File From where infoOfPosts is coming from is:

```
let evalSelector;
const selectorData = [];
async function newTab(browser, page) {
  await page.keyboard.down("Control");
  await page.click("span.Jv7Aj.mArmR.MqpiF");
  await page.keyboard.up("Control");
  await page.waitForTimeout(1000);
  const newPage = (await browser.pages())[1];
  await newPage.waitForNavigation("#react-root");
  await newPage.waitFor(20000);
  evalSelector = await selectorEvaluation(newPage, titleSelector);
  selectorData.push(evalSelector);
  evalSelector = await selectorEvaluation(newPage, noPostSelector);
  selectorData.push(evalSelector);
  evalSelector = await selectorEvaluation(newPage,
    noOfFollowersSelector);
  selectorData.push(evalSelector);
  evalSelector = await selectorEvaluation(newPage,
    noOfFollowingSelector);
  selectorData.push(evalSelector);
  evalSelector = await selectorEvaluation(newPage,
    displayNameSelector);
  selectorData.push(evalSelector);
  evalSelector = await selectorEvaluation(newPage, aboutSelector);
  selectorData.push(evalSelector);
  console.log(selectorData);
  await newPage.waitFor(5000);
  await newPage.close();
  return selectorData;
}
module.exports = newTab;
```

Any Help would be really Appreciated. Thanks in Advance.
Kudos!!

Comment: You need to create a new object each time you push into the array. You're reusing the same object.

Comment: Thanks for reaching out @Barmar. How would I do that I have like Thousands of values in my Array, so I have to create thousands of Objects??

Comment: Of course. How else would you have thousands of different values?

Comment: Move the line `let accountInfoObject = new Object();` into the code that saves the object, instead of doing it just once at the beginning.

Comment: Can You Please Explain a bit?

Comment: Post your code and I'll show how to fix it.

Comment: Ok I will edit the Post.

Comment: Added Code @Barmar

Comment: Put `let accountInfoObject = {};` right after the `let infoOfPost` assignment. You need a brand new object on each iteration of that loop.

Comment: Adding the object via `.push()` into the array **does not** make a copy of the object.

Comment: Thanks for reaching out. So what should I do?? @Pointy

Comment: I tried waht u said and now its just adding the first object over n over in array @Pointy

Comment: `selectorData` should also be a local variable in `newTab`. You're not removing the previous data before you push the information for the current page.

Comment: Yeah I've already changed that but what Pointy suggested I tried and now it just keeps adding the same first value stored init to the Array over and Over Again @Barmar

Comment: Are you sure `newTab()` is selecting different information each time?

Comment: Yes I can share Screenshot if you want.@Barmar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems.

1. You're reusing the same `accountInfoObject` every time you do `accountsInformation.push(accountInfoObject);`.

```
let accountsInformation = [];
async function scrapingPosts(browser, page) {
  readCsvFile(urlsToVisit);
  for (let x = 0; x < urlsToVisit.length; x++) {
    secondaryUrl = urlsToVisit[x];
    await page.waitFor(10000);
    await page
      .goto(`${secondaryUrl}`, {
        waitUntil: "domcontentloaded",
      })
      .catch((e) => {});
    await page.waitForSelector("article >div.EZdmt:nth-child(2)",
      5000);
    for (let i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
      await page.waitFor(5000);
      //  this loops goes through all 3 posts of each container;
      for (let j = 1; j <= 3; j++) {
        // opening the modal means clicking on post i and j will 
        increment and we will keep moving to next post 1 by 1
        await page.click(
          `div.EZdmt > div > div > div:nth-child(${i}) > div:nth-child(${j})`);
        let url = await urlOfIds(page, urlsAddress);
        await page.waitFor(5000);
        let infoOfPost = await newTab(browser, page);
        let accountInfoObject = {
            accountUrl: url,
            displayName: infoOfPost[0],
            posts: infoOfPost[1],
            followers: infoOfPost[2],
            following: infoOfPost[3],
            fullName: infoOfPost[4],
            about: infoOfPost[5]
        };
        await page.waitFor(10000);
        accountsInformation.push(accountInfoObject);
        console.log(accountsInformation);
        await objectsCsv(accountsInformation);
        // Modal Closes here process repeats till the loop condition is unsatisfied
        await page.click(
          "body > div._2dDPU.QPGbb.CkGkG > div.qF0y9._4EzTm.BI4qX.qJPeX.fm1AK.TxciK.yiMZG >button.wpO6b");
        await page.waitFor(20000);
      }
    }
  }
  await browser.close();
}
```

2. You're not clearing `selectorData` before you push the new data in `newTab()`. You should make that a local variable. So when `scrapingPosts()` uses elements 0 to 5, they're from the first post that was fetched.

```
async function newTab(browser, page) {
  await page.keyboard.down("Control");
  await page.click("span.Jv7Aj.mArmR.MqpiF");
  await page.keyboard.up("Control");
  await page.waitForTimeout(1000);
  const newPage = (await browser.pages())[1];
  await newPage.waitForNavigation("#react-root");
  await newPage.waitFor(20000);
  const selectorData = [];
  for (let selector of [titleSelector, noPostSelector, noOfFollowersSelector, noOfFollowingSelector, displayNameSelector, aboutSelector]) {
    let evalSelector = await selectorEvaluation(newPage, selector);
    selectorData.push(evalSelector);
  }
  console.log(selectorData);
  await newPage.waitFor(5000);
  await newPage.close();
  return selectorData;
}
module.exports = newTab;
```

Comment: I changed the code, it works alright but now it writes the previous values again when i pass the array to function that writes to csv... what should I do in order to get each value to write only once? @Barmar

Comment: Make `accountsInformation` local to `scrapingPosts`. Do you sense a pattern?

Comment: should it be inside any loop or simply inside scrapingPost function? @Barmar

Comment: I guess it should be inside the inner loop, since you call `objectsCsv()` each time through that loop.

Comment: So you don't really even need that variable at all. If you're just saving one object at a time, just call `await objectsCsv([accountInfoObject]);`

Comment: Let me give it a try but I think this will work. Thank you so much for your help you just saved me alot of time.

Comment: I just have a few more questions? Please leave a comment when u can.

Comment: Just write your question here and I'll be notified.

Comment: How can I filter Out the ids that have Followers less then say 2000 before i write them to csv since I am getting the textContent of the Selectors and the problem with that is the results are of type string and of the form 2.2k,5.5m 7,233 etc. Is there a way to write a conditional statement that does exactly what I want in a single if else statement? Would love to hear back from you @barmar

Comment: You'll need to write a function that parses those numbers. Take out commas, multiply by 1000 if it ends with k, by 1000000 if it ends with m, etc.

Comment: if thats not too much trouble to ask, can explain me step by step: 1. I use replace method to remove commas, then i convert it into number?? and thenn do what you have suggested???

Comment: `str = str.replace(/,/g, '')` will remove the commas from a string

Comment: Thanks alot I just wanted to know if I was on the right track and thanks again for all the help really appreciate you taking time out for me. Kudos!!

Comment: Can u please review this. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70613068/)